# Why am I getting TransactionRequiredException by invoking a @Stateless method from a bean?

Tags: java, transactions, stateless, java-ee-8

Environment:

- JBoss 7.2
- Java 11

I am trying to insert data to a DB from a JSF page through TestBean controller, but I am getting an error saying javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException that I need a transaction.
The insert method() is in a @Stateless ConsultaService, so I thought that it was by default transactional but it looks like something is wront.

This code is being migrated from JBoss 5.2 but I had no problem, when I invoked insert method() a transaction was created without any problem. Has that changed in JBoss 7.2?

Should I add @Transactional to every method? or there is something else that I am missing?

**TestBean.java **

```
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class TestBean implements Serializable {

    ...
    
    @Inject
    ConsultaServiceable consultaSvc;

    ...
    public void insert() {
        try {
            Consulta consulta1 = new Consulta();
            consulta1.setConsulta("hola");
            consulta1.setCognom1("cognom");
            consulta1.setCp("07000");
            consulta1.trace();
            consultaSvc.insert(consulta);//ERROR TransactionRequiredException
        } catch (AppException e) {
            log.error("error inserting consulta", e);
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

**BusinessServiceable.java**

```
public interface BusinessServiceable<T> extends QueryServiceable<T> {
    T insert(T entity) throws AppException;
    T update(T entity) throws AppException;
    void remove(T entity) throws AppException;
}
```

**QueryService.java**

```
public abstract class QueryService<T> extends Queryable implements QueryServiceable<T> {
    
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "bdPU")
    protected EntityManager eManager;

    protected Class<T> entityClass;

    ...

    public QueryService(Class<T> entityClass) {
        this.entityClass = entityClass;
    }
    ...
}
```

**BusinessService.java**

```
public abstract class BusinessService<T> extends QueryService<T> implements BusinessServiceable<T> {

    ...
    @PermitAll
    public T insert(T entity) throws AppException {

        try {
            eManager.persist(entity);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Error on BusinessService.insert ", e);

            Throwable t = e.getCause();

            if (t instanceof org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException) {
                throw new AppException("Error on BusinessService.insert " + entity.getClass().getSimpleName() + " id " + entity.toString(), e);
            } else {
                throw new AppException("Error on insert", e);
            }
        }

        return entity;
    }
    ...
}
```

**ConsultaService.java**

```
@Stateless
@Local
@PermitAll
public class ConsultaService extends BusinessService<Consulta> implements ConsultaServiceable {

    public ConsultaService() {
        super(Consulta.class);
    }

    @PermitAll
    @Override
    public Consulta insert(Consulta entity) throws AppException {
        return super.insert(entity);
    }
    ...
}
```

**Error server log**

```
10:46:52,329 ERROR [es.caib.accfor.business.QueryService] (default task-1) Error on BusinessService.insert : javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: WFLYJPA0060: Transaction is required to perform this operation (either use a transaction or extended persistence context)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa@7.2.0.GA-redhat-00005//org.jboss.as.jpa.container.AbstractEntityManager.transactionIsRequired(AbstractEntityManager.java:877)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa@7.2.0.GA-redhat-00005//org.jboss.as.jpa.container.AbstractEntityManager.persist(AbstractEntityManager.java:579)
    at deployment.accfor2.ear//es.caib.accfor.business.BusinessService.insert(BusinessService.java:43)
    at deployment.accfor2.ear//es.caib.accfor.business.consulta.boundary.ConsultaService.insert(ConsultaService.java:46)
    at deployment.accfor2.ear//es.caib.accfor.business.consulta.boundary.ConsultaService$Proxy$_$$_WeldSubclass.insert(Unknown Source)
    at deployment.accfor2.ear//es.caib.accfor.business.consulta.boundary.ConsultaService.insert(ConsultaService.java:14)
    at deployment.accfor2.ear.accfor-front.war//es.caib.accfor.presentation.front.TestBean.insert(TestBean.java:57)
```

Answer (score 0):

It was a problem wih pom.xml dependencies and ejb module.